# "Web container transport chains" in Websphere liberty

Tags: port, containers, websphere-liberty

My Websphere App needs to configure the "Web container transport chains" in the traditional Admin Console. But when I switch to the Liberty, I can't find it in the AdminCenter. Where can I do it?

Comment: We may not have a direct analog in Liberty for Web container transport chains. Are you simply looking to map particular ports, like the httpEndpoint server.xml example here? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_inst_bootstrap.html

Comment: I can do a mapping in the boostrap.properties, e.g. `transportChain = 1038`. But I am looking at the below steps after the mapping. where is the place to do it?`Click Servers and expand Server Types.
Click WebSphere application servers > server_name.
Expand Web Container Settings and click Web container transport settings > transport_chain_name.
Click Web container inbound channel.
Specify 32768 in the Write buffer size field, and click OK.
Click Save.` @ewhoch

Comment: Is there a particular reason for setting the write buffer size besides the recommendation in the documentation? I don't see an analogous setting in Liberty. You can get a full view of the server configuration from the documentation on server.xml elements: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/autodita/rwlp_metatype_core.html for example httpEndpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I would rethink the settings you're using for WebSphere when using WebSphere Liberty. The configuration in Liberty is entirely in the server.xml. Rarely the bootstrap.properties, usually for things that need to be set before we read the server.xml. I would try instead to simply define the HTTP endpoints you want, along with the deployed application, as seen [here.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_war.html) The full httpEndpoint configuration documentation is [here.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/autodita/rwlp_metatype_core.html?lang=en-us#mtFile90)